# How to build c#.net & .net core application together using team city

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, teamcity

I have created a visual studio project solution that contains

1. Asp.net application (C#)
2. .net core applicatin

I can build projects separately. Is it possible to build these two projects together using team city?

Comment: Hope this link help you out [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079666/how-to-configure-teamcity-to-build-a-solution-with-2-projects)

Comment: What are you doing in TeamCity right now? Shouldn't it build the whole solution?